# How can I detect that my app has been launched from a game center push notification

Tags: iphone, ios, push-notification, game-center, launching-application

I am testing an app to run in Game Center.  When the app launches from the icon I have a preamble that I want to avoid if the app is launched from Game Center (either from the Game Center app or as the target of a friend invite).  I am examining the launchOptions in my appDelegate as follows;

```
- (BOOL)application:(UIApplication *)application didFinishLaunchingWithOptions:(NSDictionary *)launchOptions
{

NSLog(@"%sThe launch options are %@", __PRETTY_FUNCTION__, launchOptions);
if (launchOptions != nil) {

    [[KYTGlobals instance] setQuickStart:YES];
}
```

...

This works fine when the the app is launched by Game Center but when it is launched on foot of a friend invite the launch options variable is NIL;

In the Provisioning portal I have enabled Push Notifications for development but not for production.

Any clues?

Comment: Is this a turn-based game using GKTurnBasedMatch?

Comment: No it is not turn based.

Answer (score 2):

I decided to submit this to Apple support but unfortunately the answer is that the functionality is not supported because this would require the UIKit to have some awareness of GameKit and would thus cause a cross framework dependancy.  I was asked to submit it as a bug.

Comment: Can you please share a bug # or specific Apple URL where this can be tracked? I'm also interested in this functionality.